# Char array assignment to another char array

Tags: c, arrays, char

I want to assign one char array to another, but the following does not work.

```
 unsigned char myval1[6] = {0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01};
 unsigned char myval2[6];
 myval2 = &myval1[0];
```

Comment: What you are trying to do gives compiler error because, an array variable here **myval1**,**myval2** are always constant type, so you cannot modify base address of an array which you are actually doing in your solution. You can follow any of the answers given below for copying your arrays.

Answer (score 2):

C-Array are not copy-assignable.
You have to do the copy yourself (using `std::copy` (C++) or `memcpy` (C)).
In C++11, you may use `std::array` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is one thing you cannot do with an assignment. One possibility is

```
memcpy( myval2, myval1, sizeof(myval2) );
```

Answer (score 1):

In `C` you an not assign the array. You should use `memcpy()` function to copy array.

```
memcpy(myval2, myval1, sizeof(myval2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this..

```
unsigned char myval1[6] = {0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01};
 unsigned char *myval2;
 myval2 = &myval1[0];
```

Comment: Probably not what OP had in mind. It creates an alias for myval1 and does not copy any values.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot assign arrays in C.

You must manually copy each array element. The standard library function to do this is `memcpy()`:

```
memcpy(myval2, myval1, sizeof myval2);
```

The final argument is the number of bytes to copy, and using `sizeof` is very much recommended. Note that if `myval1` is *smaller*  than `myval2`, the above will be undefined behavior since it will read beyond the bounds of `myval1`. You must be careful.

Answer (score 0):

A good idiom for this is:

```
memcpy(&myval2, &myval1, sizeof myval2);
```

By pairing `&x` and `sizeof x` you ensure that you always copy the right number of bytes, even if you make a mistake elsewhere with variable names.

The version suggested in the other posts works anyway because `myval2` is an array, so `(void *)myval2 == (void *)&myval2`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
unsigned int myval1[6] = {0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01};
unsigned int myval2[6];
unsigned int* add = &myval1[0];

cout << *add << endl;
```

Comment: and how does this copy the values of `myval1` to `maval2` ?

Comment: there is no myval2 here, you need to use variable add, add++ to access next values. Yes variable add address will be pointing to the starting address of myval1 so *add will print 1 ; *add++ = 1 [myval1[1]] ;  *add++ = 1 [myval1[2]]